# How to catch unhandled rejections in Bluebird when using .done()?

Tags: promise, bluebird

Usually, when unhandled rejection happens, Bluebird dispatches `unhandledrejection` event like this:

```js
// The message is logged, great!
window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", function(e) {
    console.log("got unhandled rejection")
});
Promise.reject(new Error())
```

However, as soon as I explicitly mark a promise chain as `.done()`, the event is no longer dispatched:

```js
// The message is not logged, boo!
window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", function(e) {
    console.log("got unhandled rejection")
});
Promise.reject(new Error()).done()
```

Please do not paste the boilerplate answer `"bluebird is smart enough to handle .done() for you"`. I want to specifically ask about handling uncaught rejections when `.done()` is used. In particular I need this because `unhandledrejection` is fired whenever appropriate `.catch` is attached asynchronously, which it is in my case.

In Q it works as expected (although Q actually *requires* you to finish the promise chain with `.done()`):

```js
Q.onerror = function() {
    console.log("got unhandled rejection")
};
Q.reject(new Error()).done();
```

Comment: Why are you using `done` at all?

Comment: @Bergi because he does not want to deal with `unhandledRejection`s that originated in errors where a `.catch` was attached later - and the bluebird docs don't do a good enough job of explaining the coding style change you need to make in order to benefit from `unhandledRejection`s (opt out of safety in a few places where you're sure of what you're doing instead of having to remember to call `.done` every single time). Hopefully this will be fixed in the 3.0 website - definitely something that should.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Ah, you mean an `.error(function(){})` that swallows operational errors would be more appropriate here?

Comment: Well, to be completely straight - I'm yet to see a case where attaching an error asynchronously made sense. It means there is a time frame where your system has errored but you're not aware of it - but yeah, I realize not everyone codes the same way I do so this is how you opt-out of error detection by suppressing it. (Even a `.catch(function(){})` on a new and unused branch of the promise would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call done you're explicitly asking Bluebird to convert a rejection to a thrown exception.

You can catch all of those using `window.onerror` (or the addEventListener counterpart).

```
window.onerror = function(e){
     // done makes it into a thrown exception - so catch it here.
};
```

P.S.

The reason people post the "bluebird is clever enough" boilerplate is mostly because it's right (and for what it's worth Q is too as of 1.3). Using `.done` everywhere is error prone and problematic for plenty of reasons. It's not supported in native promises either.

Comment: `window.onerror` is fired on every error, not only bluebird-related ones. Also, it does not provide the `Error` object (except of chrome and firefox)

Comment: Yes, this is true - window.onerror fires for every error - when you call `.done` you're explicitly asking bluebird to convert a rejection to an error.

Comment: regarding the boilerplate part - I updated my question

Comment: @AdamZieliński attaching error handlers asynchronously is problematic for many reasons - if you explicitly want to suppress unhandledRejections for promises _you know_ will not introduce problematic state you can do `var p = mightFail(); p.catch(function(){}); return p.then(...)` which will turn it off for that particular exception. If you just want to deal with it you can also listen to `rejectionHandled` and use whichever logic you want to determine what are false positives.